# Variable "id" does not exist in @WebProfiler/Collector/logger.html.twig at line 117

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a symfony project am i faced this problem

```
 Variable "id" does not exist in @WebProfiler/Collector/logger.html.twig at line 117
```

this is the line where the probleme is :

```
   {% if stack %}
        **<a href="#" onclick="Sfjs.toggle('{{ id }}', document.getElementById('{{ id }}-on'), document.getElementById('{{ id }}-off')); return false;">**
            <img class="toggle" id="{{ id }}-off" alt="-" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQSANft94TG57Hb8GS44ez1+mC24IvK6ePx+Wa44dXs92+942e54o3L6W2844/M6dnu+P/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABIALAAAAAASABIAQAVCoCQBTBOd6Kk4gJhGBCTPxysJb44K0qD/ER/wlxjmisZkMqBEBW5NHrMZmVKvv9hMVsO+hE0EoNAstEYGxG9heIhCADs=" style="display:none">
            <img class="toggle" id="{{ id }}-on" alt="+" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAMQTANft99/v+Ga44bHb8ITG52S44dXs9+z1+uPx+YvK6WC24G+944/M6W28443L6dnu+Ge54v/+/l614P///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAABMALAAAAAASABIAQAVS4DQBTiOd6LkwgJgeUSzHSDoNaZ4PU6FLgYBA5/vFID/DbylRGiNIZu74I0h1hNsVxbNuUV4d9SsZM2EzWe1qThVzwWFOAFCQFa1RQq6DJB4iIQA7" style="display:inline">
        </a>
    {% endif %}
```

i have no idea why is that happening, i have two questions:

1- how to solve this?

2- how can i know the reasons of all this kind of problemes ( 500 Internal Server Error ) because this is one of them .

thanks for your help.

Comment: What Symfony version do you use? To understand reasons of problems you need to read the error message, find place where it occurs and do whatever you can.

Comment: i am using symfony 2

Comment: Ok. Another question: What version of Symfony2 do you use? ;-)

Comment: Almost all problems are resolved with cache:clear

Comment: @pabgaran i clear the cache but the problem still there

Comment: @ADA15, did you see my second question about version? Maybe you have some version that have bug? Did you try to update all dependencies?

Comment: sorry , am using symfony 2.6.7 and i cleard the cache as i update my composer but i still got the same problem

Comment: please compare your code with this links of files 

https://github.com/Nicofuma/phpbb-ext-webprofiler/blob/master/styles/all/template/collector/logger.html

and 

http://sijeko.net/hglens/repo/symfony-hg/file/7d2f141270b4/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Collector/logger.html.twig

Comment: @JIGNESHVAGH i did compare and it's  the same code that i add in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i resolve this by changing the logger.html.twig

by replacing this part

```
    {% macro display_message(log_index, log, is_deprecation) %}
         {% if is_deprecation %}
              {% set stack = log.context.stack|default([]) %}
              {% if stack %}
```

whith this :

```
     {% macro display_message(log_index, log, is_deprecation) %}
           {% if is_deprecation %}
               {% set stack = log.context.stack|default([]) %}
               {% set id = 'sf-call-stack-' ~ log_index %}
               DEPRECATED - {{ log.message }}
               {% if stack %}
```